# aspectRatio = backingWidth / backingHeight?

Tags: iphone, c, opengl-es

What am I doing wrong here, I can't get the result of this division:

**aspectRatio = backingWidth / backingHeight;**

I've thought I might try casting to (GLfloat) but that didn't do anything.  As I step through the code I see that aspectRatio is 0 after the operation, while backingWidth is clearly 768 and backingHeight is 1029.

Here are the types:

```
GLfloat aspectRatio;
```

and

```
// The pixel dimensions of the CAEAGLLayer
GLint backingWidth;
GLint backingHeight;
```

It must be something basic I'm doing wrong here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast either of the values to a floating point type, otherwise the division itself is made using integers:

```
aspectRatio = (GLfloat) backingWidth / backingHeight;
```

Comment: Lesson learned.  I was thinking that these operations automatically "upgraded" the resulting datatype to the largest datatype involved.

It works now using:

 **aspectRatio = (GLfloat) backingWidth / backingHeight;**


Thanks!